# Re-configuring java environmental variables for Hadoop ecosystem

Tags: hadoop, cloudera, scala-ide

I'm trying to install Scala IDE 4.7 in my Cloudera VM 5.10, Which is preconfigured with JDK 1.7, Spark 1.6 version respectively.
    So, I have installed jdk version 1.8  in /opt/ location by uninstalling the default JDK located at /usr/java/jdk1.7 given by Cloudera. I added the java environment variables in .bash_profile. I was successfully able to install Scala IDE. 
    But now all the ecosystem of Hadoop are pointing towards old JDK 1.7 which I have uninstalled and throws an error when running. Can anyone let me know where I can config java variables for Hadoop ecosystem to work with new 1.8 JDK? 
[Here is the screen shot for reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eeD6j.png)

Answer (score 0):

Step 1: Stop all the hadoop servers
Step 2: edit bigtop-utils file.
        I've added the location of jdk 1.8.
        Create a variable BIGTOP_MAJOR = 8.
        the order of preference for it to choose the jdk is 6,7,8 and open JDK.
Step 3: save and reboot.